# concat all rows vertically and store in a paramener in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I need to concat all distinct rows and store in parameter

If I have rows like

```
1
2
3
```

I need like `1,2,3` and need to be stored in a parameter
 I tried using calculation fields but it is using index() which will not work in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can accomplish this, but the method you choose partly depends on what your visual / output needs to look like and what your dataset looks like - do you know what all of the values will be (Static values), or is there is a dynamic number of possibilities?

https://community.tableau.com/message/425925#425925

If the data is fixed, you can use a formula like this

> REPLACE( "*" +
>
>   { FIXED [Order ID] : MAX( IF [Category] = "Technology"       THEN ", Technology"      ELSE "" END ) } +
>
>   { FIXED [Order ID] : MAX( IF [Category] = "Furniture"        THEN ", Furniture"       ELSE "" END ) } +
>
>   { FIXED [Order ID] : MAX( IF [Category] = "Office Supplies"  THEN ", Office Supplies" ELSE "" END ) } , "*, ", "" )
>   , "*, ", "" )

Otherwise, look here for a more dynamic approach -- If you truly cannot use Index(), then you may have to do this at the datasource level.

https://community.tableau.com/message/180164#180164

Comment: no the data will be change, it depends on the filter